# How do I create pretty url from the GET parameters in Django?

Tags: python, django, forms, django-templates, django-urls

my query string is generated by a form with name and age, that looks something like this,

```
www.example.com/?name=Martin&age=19&place=RU
```

the form,

```
<form action="" method="get">
  Name: <input type="text" name="name"><br>
  Age: <input type="text" name="age"><br>
  Place <input type="text" name="place"><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

and I want to make the submitted url to django to be

```
www.example.com/Martin/19/RU
```

how can I do this? what should I modify on the `form` or on the `urls.py` ?

thanks

Comment: This is what forms do when to make a GET request. It's not Django related, just the HTML standard. You can use JavaScript to override this behavior or use a POST which will hide the parameters from the URL. But keep in mind, that a filled form is very different from a normal link and the behavior you are intending is not the usual way HTML forms work.

Comment: @KlausD. thanks, I'm looking for some solution to make it possible, may be post request redirection will help i guess,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script>
function changeAction() {

var profile_form = document.getElementById('profileform');
        if(profile_form) {
        var txt = "http://www.example.com/";
        var i;
        for (i = 0; i < profile_form.length; i++) {
            txt = txt + profile_form.elements[i].value + "/";
        }
           profile_form.action = txt; 
        }}
</script>
```

And in your html, you need something like this:

```
<form action="" method="get" id="profileForm" onsubmit="changeAction()">
  Name: <input type="text" name="name"><br>
  Age: <input type="text" name="age"><br>
  Place <input type="text" name="place"><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

I guess this should do the trick.

Comment: Just a comment...you don't actually need the `|| null` part, as `.getElementById()` will return `null` [if the element is not in the document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById)

Comment: Yeah, wasn't needed. Corrected.

Comment: You should use encodeURIComponent(profile_form.elements[i].value) to make sure it is url compliant !